# Which Stack Exchange accepts computer related questions about Debian?

Tags: support, se-sites

Does Stack Exchange have a site for computer related questions similar to Math Stack Exchange? I mean one which accepts beginner questions as well, specifically about Debian. If so, what is the URL?

Comment: It is not clear what exactly you seek. Maybe [SU]

Comment: What quid mentioned above got something related to operating systems (including Linux), but you might have a better chance [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) (search for the Debian tag).

Answer (score 4):

We have two sites in the network with a lot of questions about using Debian:

- [Super User](https://superuser.com/tags/debian) (5k questions)
- [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/debian) (11k questions)

As long as your question is clear and you describe what research you've done, I guess it would work on both sites. [This](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3647/111051) is a fair and (IMHO) balanced answer about when to post on either site. If I may summarize: if you have a beginner *end-user* question, use Super User; for a beginner *administrator* question, use Unix & Linux.

Comment: I'd also look for a certain level of information on [askUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) since Ubuntu is a Debian based distribution, and there is a well-used tag for [debian](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=debian).

Comment: @hardmath it's Debian based, yes, but have you read the tag information? https://askubuntu.com/tags/debian/info

Comment: Yes, I did read that.